# Router generate wrong URL on Shopware testenvironment

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I use the following code in a Shopware 6 Plugin for a Controller response:

```
return new RedirectResponse(
  $this->router->generate('frontend.cart.offcanvas', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
);
```

When I run this plugin on my dockware, the Controller set the following correct redirect header:

**location: /checkout/offcanvas**

When is use the same plugin on the shopware testenvirement the redirect header is:

**location: http://****-hzvhn.sw-testenvironment.de/shop/public/**

It's not an absolute path, right? And it's not the requested route. This ends in a blocked request, because mixed content - testenvirement runs on https.

When I use **UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL** for the router generation, I got on my local instance a correct URL with the same protocol, on the testenvirement also a http URL.

Symfonys doc of the UrlGeneratorInterface gives me a clear statement what to expect, so I wonder about the response https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGeneratorInterface.php
Is the testenvirement of shopware misconfigured or I have a thinking error?

Comment: What is the URL the [domain of your sales channel](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/saleschannel#domain) is set to?

Comment: @dneustadt On my local instance its "http://localhost" on the sw-testenvironment it's "https://***-divfs.sw-testenvironment.de/shop/public"